# Multiple Scrollviews?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, scroll

I don't really know how to explain what I want, so here's an picture :
[image]

I have a view with a lot of subviews (gray lines). Then the background (blue) is a picture (UIImageView + Blur effect), so I need it to stay and not to scroll. Behind the background, there's a view (orange). I want the picture (blue) to scroll only when the subviews (gray) are at the bottom (3rd picture).

Should I use embed scrollviews, or can I get this effect with only one UIScrollView ? If multiple scrollviews, does someone have an example ?

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

Use only one scroll view, and use its delegate method 'scrollViewDidScroll' to read the content offset. Use this value to translate your background image.

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary to use 2 scroll views. But I would use it since I prefer setting `contentOffset` of the background scroll view than setting it's frame directly.

The idea is that you implement `scrollViewDidScroll:` delegate method for the front scroll view. And track the `contentOffset` to check whether the scrolling has reached the end of it's content by checking whether `scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.bounds.size.height > scrollView.contentSize.height` or not.

If it has, then you offset the location of the background view with the amount of offset that exceed the content size.

Please see the code below. You can skip all the code and only look at `scrollViewDidScroll:`.

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.tableView.delegate = self;

    self.backgroundScrollView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 20;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Item %ld", (long)indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    CGFloat backgroundVerticalOffset = MAX(scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.bounds.size.height - scrollView.contentSize.height, 0);
    CGPoint backgroundContentOffset = CGPointMake(0.0, backgroundVerticalOffset);
    self.backgroundScrollView.contentOffset = backgroundContentOffset;
    // If you decide not to use two scroll views, then please use backgroundContentOffset to set the backgroundView.frame.origin.y instead
    // e.g. backgroundView.frame.origin.y = -backgroundContentOffset;
}
```

The result shown below:

[image: scrolling]

P.S. I used blue background view instead of an image view and everything else with clear background color.

Comment: In your example, what is the storyboard hierarchy ? The blue background view is a subview of : the backgroundScrollView or a subview of the backgroundScrollView ?

Comment: `backgroundScrollView` is placed behind `tableView`. They're sibling. The blue background view is the subview of `backgroundScrollView`.

Comment: Oh, and in your example the scrollview doesn't stay in the upper position, does it ? What if I want the scrollview to stay in the upper position when the drag end ?

Comment: What do you mean "stay in the upper position"?

Comment: I mean when you stop clicking (when the white view is not hidden), the scrollview don't replace itself and the white view stay visible